# Python 3.6 очень странное поведение при вводе больших файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть кусок кода:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
p = []

line = f.readline()
while line:
    #print(line, end='')
    p.append(line)
    line = f.readline()

f.close()
```

Суть проблемы: без `print()` python выкидывает исключение `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 7495: character maps to <undefined>`.
Самая соль в том, что добавление print решает проблему.

Очень важно, что я ввожу довольно большой файл (2.73 Гб), наверняка это играет свою роль. Файл мне надо ввести посрочно, сделать `random.shuffle()` и вывести блоками по 15-20М строк в несколько файлов. Проблемы появились ещё при вводе.

Также важно, что на моём компьютере 7Гб ОЗУ, а когда всё закрыто свободно 4-4.5 Гб. Вроде достаточно, чтобы ввести файл, но память тоже важный фактор.

Отмечу, что если использовать `f.readlines()` для ввода, проблема не пропадает.

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать кодировку, например f = open('data.txt', encoding="utf8")

Comment: @avtomato Спасибо, так заработало. И всё рано это явно неправильное поведение для программы. Не могу понять, как тут задействован print и почему с ним ошибка вдруг пропадала.

Comment: Какая-то тёмная виндовая магия. А хотя бы кусочек файла можно посмотреть?

Comment: @andreymal Увы, нет. Не хочу проблем с правилами сайта. Нашёл сайт с большим количеством "слитых" баз и захотелось посмотреть, чего в текстовом файле может быть на 3Гб. Там просто куча строк формата "inf1 : inf2".

Comment: Впрочем, а что конкретно имеется в виду под «добавление print решает проблему» — программа отрабатывает полностью до конца без ошибок? Или вы @ЕгорЛевоненко даже не пробовали ждать, пока все эти гигабайты с принтом прочитаются?)

Comment: @andreymal: вопрос откуда `UnicodeDecodeError` берётся и дубликат объясняет откуда¶ Если автор эту часть понял (какую кодировку open() по умолчанию использует) и отредактирует вопрос, указав это, тогда можно print обсуждать (я думаю -- это тривиально -- print просто замедляет программу, автор не успел увидеть ошибку -- могу ошибаться, но пока вопрос с кодировкой не решён -- бессмысленно обсуждать).

Comment: @jfs Исключение выбрасывает после самого первого readline(), смыла ждать пока всё отработает просто не было.

Comment: то есть у вас ошибка ещё *до* цикла возникает. Но если вы добавите `print()` *внутрь* цикла, то ошибка *до* цикла не возникает? Вы это поведение можете воспроизвести?

Comment: @jfs Только что попробовал. Очень странно, но с print внутри while не выдаёт исключение вообще, а без print внутри while вылетает ещё до while.

Comment: Всё это конечно с условием того, что в open не выставлен аргумент encoding..

Comment: вы уверены, что нужный Питон-скрипт запускаете? Обновите вопрос как в моём комментарии выше описано. Ещё можно добавить вывод `print(open('data.txt', 'rb').readline())` ; `print(open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8').readline())`  и  убедиться, что `open('data.txt', encoding='cp1251').readline()` к ошибке ведёт (если  `locale.getpreferredencoding(False) == 'cp1251'`).